# When should I make a new method vs class vs object?

Tags: java, class, object, methods

In what situations would be more appropriate to just make a new object, and what other situations would be more appropriate for a new method or class?
I know that syntactically, it doesn't really matter, but I want to know what is good style and what is not.

Comment: Can you narrow down your question a bit?

Comment: This question will likely be closed. I suggest you try asking on a more discussion-focused forum such as dreamincode.net or daniweb.com

Comment: I'm reading Head First Design Patterns to better understand this myself.

Comment: This seems to be asking how do OO design when you don't understand how objects and classes work.  The answer is ... you need to understand how object and classes work >>first<<.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of this discussion, I'm going to consider class and object one in the same, as object is just an instance of a class.

Generally you create a class to represent some *thing*.  Methods are used to add behavior to that *thing*.  So, if you have something new you want to model, you want to add a class.  If you want to add behavior to one of your existing models, add a method.